# Network error: in RHEL 6.6 while doing yum install

Tags: rhel, yum

I'm getting below error when do `yum install libgcj`

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
Network error:
```

After that, it was not installing package `libgcj` which I requested.

Whats the problem in the machine?
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

`yum install libgcj --noplugins` solved my problem.

Comment: Could you explain the error ? otherwise your answer doesn't "solve" your question.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, when I run `yum install libgcj` in the terminal, I was getting `Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, product-id, refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin, security, subscription-manager
Network error:` error in the terminal. 

And it was not installing the dependency `libgcj ` which I requested. 

That was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the same command with more verbosity `yum -v install libgcj12` or debug output `yum -d10 install libgcj12`.

The additional output should lead you to the root cause for that network error.